# Document data classes on Android

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I need to create an Android application with multiple pages with similar contents. They will be dynamically generated, similar to multiple text documents in Notepad++. If I would be programming this in MFC I would use multiple instances of a class derived from CDocument to store the data and multiple instances of a class derived from CMDIView to display it.

I can't seem to find a class similar to CDocument in the Android API. The Activity class seems to be geared towards applications working with one document at a time and the ContentProvider class seem to be designed for providing services to other applications.

Where would it be the best class to keep document data on the Android platform for an application that works with multiple documents at the same time? Each document would have its own view.

Comment: are you looking for a storage that supports formatting or you just want to store pure text ?

Comment: The documents are not actually text, they are graphic. I used a text editor just to exemplify the interface concepts. Also, the persistent storage is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one Activity with it's proper layout.When you want to add another doc,keep a reference to current `ContentView` of Activity(for example in V1) and inflate another instance from your layout and set it as new ContentView for your Activity and keep a reference to it(for example in V2).When you want to get data from first doc,you can get it from V1 and when you want get data from second one,get it from V2.

Answer (score 0):

**Storage**

Well the document concept in Android is not available out of the box.
instead android provide you with private storage `desk space` that no one has access to except your app *unless the device is rooted then anyone can see it* to do whatever you want with.

to access this storage folder just call [Environment.getDataDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDataDirectory%28%29)

if you are looking to store simple datatypes (int, float, String ....) :

- You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for out of box functionality.
- Or you can write your own xml/json parser and store in the above mentioned directory.

if you are looking for generic storage (object or byte) based you are going to have to write your own wrapper above a `File` Object.

**Views**

it seems like you are looking for some sort of dynamically generated (master/detail) MVC which can be implemented in a lot of ways in android. on top of my head you can use:

- Activity with a listview and another activity for your canvas,[take a look here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)
- ActionBar based app with fragments. [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html)
- ViewFlipper based app [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-dog-limps-into-a-saloon-a-tutorial-on-androids-viewflipper-widget/634)

Hope that helps